# Why is my API in React app fetching slower in Firefox compared to Chrome?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, setinterval

I've an API which I am fetching using setInterval every 7(constant) mins. The API seems to fetch data slower when compared to Chrome. Why is this happening and how to fix this?

Comment: I am experiencing unstable behaviour as well with react fetch in Firefox, It is slower but sometime Firefox decide to block the content fetched over https://ipfs gateway